# error en respuesta json de ajax al enviar peticion

Tags: javascript, ajax, post

tengo una función con una petición ajax de post, el cual me da error

```
function enviarpregunta(pregunta){


    //DATOS QUE SE VAN A ENVIAR
    var dataToSend = {};
    var dataToSend = {

      cmd: 'get_openai_chat_answer',
      key: clave,
      data: {
        question: 'Humano: '+pregunta
    }
}
console.log(dataToSend);
console.log(JSON.stringify(dataToSend));
var dataajson=JSON.stringify(dataToSend);
console.log("dataajson: "+dataajson);
    // JQUERY PARA ENVIAR
    $.ajax({ 
        url: urlenvio, 
        type: "POST",
        datatype : "application/json", 
        contentType: "application/json",
        //los datos los paso a json
        data: dataajson,
        success: function(json_response) { 
            **console.log(JSON.stringify(json_response));
            var entradaExitolistJson = JSON.parse(json_response);**


            if (entradaExitolistJson.code == 0) {



            var respuesta=entradaExitolistJson.data.openai_text;
            console.log("respuesta -> "+respuesta)



        }//fin primer if

            //mostrar un modal o alert si el codigo no es 0
            if (entradaExitolistJson.code != 0)  {
               alert("error: "+entradaExitolistJson.code)
               
                 }
             },
             error: function(xhr, status, error) {        }     

    });//el del ajax

    }//fin función
```

me da error en la parte que he puesto con "**"

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
at JSON.parse ()
at Object.success (botones.js:189:49)
esa es la linea que me da el error...

console.log(JSON.stringify(json_response));
en ese console me aparece el string vacio (aparece: "") pero si ejecuto la función en postman si me da respuesta...

Comment: Agrega a tu pregunta que te sale cuando haces `console.log(json_response)`

Comment: ya lo puse, aparece ("")

Comment: Entonces una de dos... o el servidor no está devolviendo nada, o lo que tienes es un problema de CORS, revisa si en la consola de errores te sale algo relacionado con CORS

Comment: de CORS no me aparece nada, lo que si en postman tarda unos segundos en recibir la respuesta
         {"code":0,"msg":"ok","data":{"text":"respuesta dada."}}

Comment: Entonces debes tener alguna diferencia en  la manera en la que envias los datos desde postman y como los envias con ajax

Comment: es que es lo raro, he copiado y pegado otro ajax que envia una petición de login, y he cambiado key y tal para poderlo en la nueva petición... el login si me lo hace bien pero esto no... puede ser por que no recibe los datos rapidamente? (300 ms en login 3segundos en esta peticion)

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136333/discussion-between-pipe-and-ebsigma).

Comment: Hola, al final el problema estaba en MI chrome.... cargué el codigo en otro chrome de otro pc y funciona perfectamente...